# How do I get a char out of a ascii value

Tags: c#, casting, ascii

Firstly this is my code:

```
int asciiValue;
string str = "a";
        
foreach(var c in str)
{
    asciiValue = (int)c;
    Console.WriteLine(asciiValue);
}
```

So my output here is 97, that's the ASCII value of "a". How can I make the 98 back into an "a" now?

Comment: `(char)asciiValue`? [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/liyqBT)

Comment: @DM and how can i do this out of the foreach loop?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. How can you do what outside of the `foreach` loop?

Comment: I want to do to something like this: var p = (char)asciivalue; outside the foreach loop but that doesn't work like that

Comment: Because you're getting a [CS0165](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165) "Use of unassigned local variable 'asciiValue'" error? If `str` were empty, then your `foreach` loop would execute without ever writing a value to `asciiValue`.

Comment: Name does not exist in the current context @DM

Comment: It sounds like you need to [read about scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#scopes). Your variable is not accessible from all places in your program. There are rules about where you can and cannot access it that are fundamental to programming in C#.

Comment: @DM yeah I know about scopes I’m not that new, but somehow I got to achieve that I can access the variable from outside.

Comment: Then simply show the failing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easy, you simply cast the value into a char.

```
int asciiValue = 98;
Console.WriteLine((char)asciiValue);
```